# A simple UML case

Tags: uml

I have tables: user, comment and post, say:

1. A user can have many posts and comments
2. A post can have many comments
3. A comment can only be written by one user, and can only be in one post

So, how can I make the relations between those tables, in way that results in no closed relation.

this is what I did :

```
tbl_user 1 ------ n  Post 
tbl_post 1--------n Comments
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your approach is good, but you should also establish a `tbl_user: 1..n Comment` relationship (assuming not only the owner of a post can make a comment) to identify the relationship between the comment and its owner.

Comment: But don't you think it's a problem to make a closed relation? between user comment, comment post , and post user?

Comment: Why would that be a problem?  Your example would yield the owner of a post the current user made a comment on

Comment: Just forget, :)) , when I was at studies, one of my professors said that this is not good to make a closed relation between tables , But I see that it works , thank you and best answer +1